# java equivalent for system() command in perl

Tags: java

Can I use Runtime to achieve the same? If so what are the pros/cons
I have to invoke a shell script from java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Runtime.exec()` to execute a shell script from Java. Of course this will make it less cross-platform and harder to maintain. If you want to wait for the shell script to finish you need to use the Process object returned by `exec()` and call `waitFor()`. You can also get the `stdin/out/err` which is very useful. You might also want to explicitly call the correct shell e.g. `exec("sh script.sh")`.

Comment: thanks for this. I found another one ProcessBuilder class but for my purpose Runtime will do

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, use `Runtime.exec()`.**

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command param param");
```

I don't understand pros/cons.  This works.  If you need to execute a shell script from java, you should use this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("the_script.sh");
```

The new process will inherit the environment of the Java process.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more control about creation of the process, [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is a more powerful alternative to `Runtime.exec(...)`.